# Qt, using COM elements in designer

Tags: qt, activex

I have a 3rd party typelib called "IpeDisp.tlb" and want to add it to Qt.
My solution was to use the dumpcpp-tool to generate the neccessary .cpp and .h files and add it with:

```
TYPELIBS  = "IpeDisp.tlb" 

isEmpty(TYPELIBS) {
    message("Error typelibs")
} else {
    HEADERS  = "ipedisp.h"
    SOURCES  = "ipedisp.cpp"
}
```

And I got the following error:

```
Fehler: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'release\ipedisp.obj'
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong?

And another question:
Visual Studio allows to "add" COM-elements to the designer, so you can drag&drop them inside the designer. Is this also possible in Qt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your project doesn't make much sense. If the `.h` and `.cpp` files already exist, then you don't need the `.tlb`. If they don't exist, then you need to invoke dumpcpp yourself. Namely:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += axcontainer
TYPELIBS = $$system(dumpcpp IpeDisp.tlb -o IpeDisp )
SOURCES += $$PWD/IpeDisp.cpp
HEADERS += $$PWD/IpeDisp.h
```